# Объясните re.sub(r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", "WordWordWord")

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Здраствуйте, можете пожалуйста объяснить что означают символы(для чего нужен каждый из них)

```
re.sub(r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", "WordWordWord")
```

К сведению, я изучаю python месяц.

Comment: первый символ — `r` — это первая буква из имени `re` (вероятно, имеется ввиду модуль https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). ну а дальше, думаю, уже не сложно разобраться.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/8cicYB/2

Answer (score 1):

В приведенном примере

```
re.sub(r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", "WordWordWord")
         ^||^|||||||     |||||   < Первая группа
          ^^ |||||||     |||||   < Эквивалентно диапазонам [A-Za-z0-9_]
             ^|||||^     |||||   < Вторая группа
              ^^^^^      |||||   < диапазон латинских буквенных символов в верхнем регистре
                         ^^|||   < возвращаем первую группу
                           ^||   < пробел
                            ^^   < возвращаем вторую группу
```

`re.sub` - Возвращает новую строку, полученную в результате замены по указанному шаблону

```
re.sub("шаблон замены", "на что меняем", "данные для изменения")
```

`r""` - текст в raw, считать спецсимволы обычным текстом

```
>>>print("\ttext")
<<<    text

>>>print(r"\ttext")
<<<\ttext
```

При запуске изначальной команды текст `WordWordWord` заменится на `Word Word Word`

---

Вопрос в том, как должна работать замена текста в случае встречи текста где все буквы пишутся в верхнем регистре, для примера `WORD`, данное регулярное выражение установит пробелы следующим образом: `W OR D`.
Для того, что бы разделение проходило под одиночные символы, вторую часть выражения следует заменить на позитивный просмотр вперед и  убрать подстановку второй группы, так как ее больше не существует:

```
re.sub(r"(\w)(?=[A-Z])", r"\1 ", "WORD")
              ^^
```

результатом в данном случае будет `W O R D`